# Set attribute value from other attribute

Tags: attributes, model, attribute-set, shell

I have custom attribute 'brand'. I should set its value in attribute 'manufacturer'. How can i do this? For now, all that i cat do ->
shell file

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/../app/Mage.php';
Mage::app('admin');

$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('manufacturer', Null);
$avid = $product->getResource()->getAttribute('brand');
$product->setData('manufacturer', $avid)->save();
```

There the mistake or maybe it is fundamentally wrong?
And it must be replaced in all products

Answer (score 2):

For me saving Product object for single data is not good idea, its take to much time. you can try below code which will help you to reduce time as well ,

and if you are saving data from shell then set store as admin.

```
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID); //set admin store for current opration

$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('manufacturer', Null);

$avid = $product->getResource()->getAttribute('brand');
$product->setData('manufacturer', $avid);
$product->getResource()->saveAttribute($product, 'manufacturer');
```

Comment: Its not working for me `$avid` is null for me Even there's value for that attribute. Can you update code regarding this ? That will be great. Thanks.

Comment: @TBSMage you can try `$product->getAttribute('brand');`

Comment: @TBSMage you are always welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

Load all products from store then get `brand` attribute value and assign it to `manufaturer`
 (*Manufaturer assumed to be created by admin already*)

```
$product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);

$brandValue=$prod->getData('brand');

$product->setData('manufacturer', $brandValue);
$product->save();
```

Run below script in root folder

Create an script at magento  root `update.php` and put the below code :

```
<?php
require_once  "app/Mage.php";
Mage::app("admin");
umask();


$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')->addAttributeToSelect('brand');

foreach($collection as $product){
$val=$product->getBrand();

$product->setManufacturer($val);
$product->getResource()->saveAttribute($product, 'manufacturer');
$product->save();

}
```